# What is the difference between "regretting one's decision" and " going back on one's decision"?

Tags: ambiguity

1- I regretted my decision to go  there.
2- I went back on my decision to go there.

Did the narrator go to that given place or not?

Comment: #2 is *reneging*.  #1 is not.

Comment: You can only regret what has already taken place  : )

Comment: @stevesliva ! Thanks, I got a bit confused, Which one means that he has gone there? 1 or 2?

Comment: It doesn't read naturally to me with the "for" used in that way. "Amy had been eager when she first applied to be the housekeeper at Castle Doom, but soon she regretted that decision" = she did it but it didn't turn out well. With "but soon she went back on her decision" instead, it implies she cancelled her decision. But we don't know if she just decided not to go, or if she got there but ran away terrified later.

Comment: @Mysti! Thanks, I didn't pay attention to that point! I got it now!:)

Comment: @mysti True, but if the regret is for the *decision* the question remains - did you go and regret the decision or did you not go and regret making the decision despite not having acted on it.

Comment: @Silverfish! Shall I omit "for"? How should I edit my sentences?

Comment: @GetzelR, Valid, agree. And if the regret is for the "decision", the answer rests with the narrator. : )-

Comment: Someone who regrets a decision may or may not go back on it.  The first sentence therefore doesn't tell us with any certainty whether the speaker went there.

Comment: Yes, you are right! @phoog! It seems that we cannot understand the real meaning of the sentence 1 unless we know the previous sentences,too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regret about a decision is your feeling about having made it; your going back on your decision is your action to reverse it.

So if you decide to go to Mexico for a vacation and have a terrible time, then you regret that choice.  If you decide to go to Mexico and later decide to go back on that decision, then you won't have made the trip.

Comment: Agreed. I would add that regret is ambiguous in this respect - you can regret the decision before or after acting on it, while going back on a decision can only occur before.

Comment: So in sentence 2 we are sure that he hasn't gone there, am I right?@GetzelR!

Comment: @Soudabeh Correct. Although "for going there" should be "to go there," I'd think